# jquery-mobile backbone.js routing

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js / jquery mobile app:

when i make a GET to mydomain.com/#map, then jquery executes "/" and then loads #map.

because "/" is triggered first, all backbone.js scripts are loaded including the backbone.js routes in my map-controller.js ("map":  "functionForMapRoute"). 
since the URL contains /#map, the backbone.js route "map" gets triggered before jquery mobile has rendered the dom.

so "functionForMapRoute" can´t operate on divs cause the DOM isn´t fully loaded at this point.

how can i ensure, that the "map" route is triggered not until the DOM is fully loaded?

Comment: pageshow: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use something more integrated with jquery mobile, for instance [jquerymobile-router](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router) (you can find it on github). It replaces backbone's router and it's to be used with jquery mobile and backbone.js or spine.js

Comment: jqm is meant to be used with backbone.js mixing in another routing facility can't be propper the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that if you dont use "/" in backbone router it will do fine.

e.g.:

use

```
"category-:id": "category"
```

instead of this

```
"category/id/:id": "category"
```

I guess thats why they used same concept in the official tutorial :P
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/Backbone-Require/js/routers/mobileRouter.js

```
"category?:type": "category"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and here is the solution to avoid using jquerymobile-router : [Backbone.js and jQueryMobile routing without hack or other router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172294/backbone-js-and-jquerymobile-routing-without-hack-or-other-router/7196257#7196257)