# JQueryMobile MVC and offline persistence

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, persistence

What would be your best combination of tools to build a JQuery Mobile application that :

- handles many kinds of objets with relations
- has many (many) different edition screens
- has to work offline, server sync is performed lastly (dedicated screen) ; *Application and media caching will be done using HTML5 manifest*

Despite my reasonably good experience in OOP, I feel quite confused when it comes to Javascript and its abounding MVC frameworks.

- **persistence.js** seems to be a good and intelligible candidate. Navigation is done manually though ;
- **backbone.js + backbone-relational + backbone-localstorage/websql** brings a nice MVC layer. Examples look nice on simple apps ; Wonder how well it couples with JQueryMobile's routing ;
- your idea ?

Thank you in advance for sharing your recommandations !

Notes :

- http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2011/12/introduction-to-backbonejs-with-jquery.html
- http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html
- https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational
- [jquery-mobile backbone.js routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466300/jquery-mobile-backbone-js-routing)
- [Backbone.js and jQueryMobile routing without hack or other router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172294/backbone-js-and-jquerymobile-routing-without-hack-or-other-router)
- https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router

Answer (score 0):

I use this stack for my applications and it seems to work well: jquery mobile + jquerymobile router + backbone/underscore + persistence.js.

The integration between backbone and persistence is done "manually" by overriding the 'save' method of my models. Takes a few minutes to implement from scratch but it's quite easy to do.

However, I think that backbone-relational + backbone-localstorage/websql shouldn't clash with jqm routing, as long as you don't use the Backbone.Router