# Why won't Backbone.js router work in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, backbone.js, routes

Have a problem on iOS:
routes without arguments (`"page1":"page1Controller"`) work well, but routes with params didnt work (`"bizObject/:id":"bizObjectController"`) - error loading page.

The link to this page has a href: `"#bizObject/6"` for example.

On Android all works well...

Comment: Yes, jQueryMobile use too for example in my Router.changePage

Comment: So now i know that webkit replace URL`s: `.../index.html#page/5` => `.../page/5`. Why? How I can route my Backbone.js application without slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into a problem of incompatibility of jQuery Mobile and Backbone default router. Both libraries modify URL fragments on their own and the behavior you see is the result of their clash. Not sure why it works on Android -- maybe there your app is using `pushState`?

To solve this, look at Backbone routers that are adapted to use with jQuery Mobile, as explained in this question: [jquery-mobile backbone.js routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466300/jquery-mobile-backbone-js-routing)

Comment: Thank you! Powerful router! Now I`m not sure too - why on Android work well.. )